# Regular expression for strings with length not a multiple of 10

Tags: formal-languages, regular-language

Let $P = \{z^n \mid \text{$n$ is not divisible by $10$} \}$.

Give a regular expression for this language and then a generalized regular expression that is shorter than the regular expression.

Comment: Usually, we put conditions on $n$ inside the braces, such as $$\{z^n: n\text{ not divisible by }10\}$$

Answer (score 3):

HINT: Every integer $n\ge 0$ can be written uniquely in the form $n=10q+r$, where $q$ and $r$ are non-negative integers, and $r<10$. If $n\ge 0$, the word $z^n$ is therefore $z^{10q+r}=z^{10q}z^r=(z^{10})^qz^r$.

Answer (score 0):

If the goal is to get a short expression, one may propose $(z^{10})^*z(1 + z + z^2)(1 + z^3 + z^6)$, which looks slightly shorter than the solution $(z^{10})^*(z + z^2 + z^3 + z^4 + z^5 + z^6 + z^7 + z^8 + z^9)$ suggested by Brian M. Scott. If extended regular expressions are allowed, then simply write $P$ as the complement of $(z^{10})^*$.